# Making Tweepy work behind Proxy

Tags: python-3.x, proxy, tweepy

I am trying to make tweepy work from behind a proxy. I have gone through every stack exchange posting on this - cant seem to make it work. Been a frustrating journey so far. I have included my code below. Any help to debug this would be sincerely appreciated. I am using the x.get('https') approach to make it general. I have tried to type in the https url directly as well. Did not work.
Thanks

```
from urllib.request import getproxies
x=getproxies()

import tweepy
from tweepy import OAuthHandler

consumer_key = 'MY CONSUMER KEY'
consumer_secret = 'MY CONSUMER SECRET'
access_token = 'MY ACCESS TOKEN'
access_secret = 'MY ACCESS SECRET'

auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth,proxy=x.get('https'))
r = api.search(q='pizza')
```